# How do I setup a logistic regression in R for a longitudinal survey dataset?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey, longitudinal

I'm working with a longitudinal survey dataset in R that asks respondents questions around employment status, wellbeing, health, etc. The dataframe combines 12 survey waves from 2009 to 2020 and I've subsetted it to only include longitudinal data on respondents who were classed as economically inactive in 2020 (and these respondents' data from previous waves).

I'm looking to run a logistic regression with Active Status in 2020 as Inactive (1) as the outcome and Overtime hrs when the Inactive respondents were last classed as Active as the predictor. I'm a bit stuck on what the correct process this is - I'm more familiar with cross-sectional analysis. Can anyone help?

Below is an example of what the dataframe looks like:

| Respondent ID | Year | Active status | Overtime hrs (week) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 157586 | 2020 | Inactive (1) | Inapplicable |
| 157586 | 2019 | Active (0) | 20 |

Respondent ID allows me to track respondents across survey waves, Year is when the survey was administered, Active status is a categorical factor variable designating respondents' work status with "0" for Active and "1" for Inactive.